# Is it possible to call instantiated static methods in other class in php?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

Is it possible to call static methods using ***Class Instance*** in the extending classes? I don't know to get the `$this->access` from parent `__construct()` all through my classes when extending it so maybe an expert in PHP could help me.

```
namespace Folder\Subfolder;

class ClassA {  // <-- this class is a custom helper

  public static function accessA() {
    return 'Class A\'s Access';
  }

  public static function accessB() {
    return 'Class B\'s Access';
  }

}
```

**In other file:**

```
use Folder\SubFolder\ClassA;

class ParentClass {

  public function __construct() {
    $this->access = new \Folder\Subfolder\ClassA;
  }

  public function admin() {
   $ac = $this->access::accessA(); 

   //When I do this it gives me an error syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)

   $ac = $this->access->accessA();

   //When I also do this it gives me an error Call to a member function accessA() on null

   var_dump($ac);
   exit;
  }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentsClass { 

 public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
 }

 public function employee() {
  $ac = $this->access::accessB();
  var_dump($ac);
  exit;
 }
}

class ChildClass2 extends ParentClass {
  public function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
  }
} //And so on and so forth
```

**NOTE:** I don't want to instantiate another class object using `new` keyword.
 I want to use this code `$this->access;` only

Comment: So there's no way I could do this? Can you suggest any other options?

Comment: It give's me an error of `Class name must be a valid object or a string`

Comment: But when I do `$access = new Folder\Subfolder\Class;` then `var_dump($access::AccessA)` it works.

Comment: Sorry. I'm still confused and can't get it. `Foo::$bar['baz']()` What is `['baz']` in this piece of code?

Comment: Tnx @PaulCrovella I get it now. :)